# Java - Scanner: does hasNext() changes accordingly after setting useDelimiter()?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

Code:

```
    Scanner input;
    File file = new File("Latex3.bib");
    input = new Scanner(file);
    input.useDelimiter("@ARTICLE");
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("It should not print this");
        s = input.next();
        System.out.println("Token"+c+": "+s);
        c++;
        author = s.substring
                (s.indexOf("author={")+8, 
                        s.indexOf("}", s.indexOf("author={")+8));
        System.out.println("Authors for this ARTICLE: "+author);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

(in the code, `c` is an `int` that I declared earlier in the original code for just counting and increasing by each loop).

I was getting weird exception from the code that I think it should not throw. After testing each input files, it turns out my while loop runs even when there's no "@ARTICLE" in the Latex3.bib file.

As far as I know, if the file does not have "@ARTICLE", that means that `input` does not get any token. So from the beginning, its `hasNext()` should return `false`. But it just wasn't.

The part what I think funny and strange is: if Latex3.bib is completely empty(not even one space bar or enter), the while loop or whatever reads it as an empty file, therefore no token is given to `input`. 
However, if Latex3.bib has like 1~3 linebreak(enters), then that while loop runs. I have no idea why this is happening. I am suspecting that `Scanner.useDelimiter(pattern)` does not affect or at least cooperate perfectly with other Scanner methods like `hasNext()`, although I believe this won't be the real case because it's a very crucial functionality.

edit:
Just to be clear what exception I got, the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` was thrown at the point of assigning `author(String)`. Well it's obvious because the file was empty... and there was nothing to `substring` or find index..

Comment: A Scanner will read input until a delimiter or EOF is encountered (i.e. last line does not have to be delimited).

Comment: Can you show the piece of Latex3.bib that is not working as you excepted please ?

Comment: The Latex3.bib file is literally a .txt file with 2~3 linebreaks(enter) and saved as a .bib file by renaming the format..

Comment: @rustyx So even if there's no delimiter and Scanner object cannot find any valid token, if there's anything written then `hasNext()` will return true? That seems a bit difficult to address...